# Django: how can I display 1 field item as a header w/ remaining field items as the value?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a table displayed inside a collapsible, accordion style card component that contains three `Field`items (one per`<td>`). Using a `forloop.counter`, I am trying display each `obj.frequency` as the collapsible-header with all of the associated `obj.product` and `obj.price` items displaying within the `collapsible-body`.

I recognize the current layout needs to be DRY-er by only using the `object.rate_set.all` loop once. I left the two obj forloops since this is the only way I can get the data within the collapsible-body section of the card, even though the data is not separated correctly.

**Question**:
How can I display the data associated with `frequency` inside a card body with the `frequency` obj output as the header?

*In addition to my template, a screenshot of my browser is included below for clarification if needed*

**My Template:**

```
 <div class="card">
   <div class="card-body">
      <ul class="collapsible popout">

        {% for obj in object.rate_set.all %}
        <!-- -------------------------------------------------
             displays each `frequency` obj in its own accordion card 
             as the header. output: 1x, 3x, 6x, 12x, 24x.. 
             ------------------------------------------------- -->
          {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
            <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header“>{{ obj.frequency }}</div>
                <div class ="collapsible-body">
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

                  <div class="table-responsive card-text">
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Product</th>
                          <th>Rate</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      <!-- -----------------------------------
                        displays all of the obj's in the last 
                        accordion card (24x)
                        ------------------------------------- -->
                       {% for obj in object.rate_set.all %}
                          <tr>
                            <td> {{ obj.product }} </a>
                            <td>${{ obj.price }}</td>
                          </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                   </div>
                  </div> <!–- end of ‘collapsible-body' -->         
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You can use regroup in your template. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup (dont forget to order_by on the regroup field in your view or it wont work)

Comment: Thanks, @DisneylandSC! that worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @DisneylandSC's response- below is the updated working template:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    {% regroup object.rate_set.order_by by frequency as frequency_list %}
    <ul class="collapsible popout">
      {% for frequency in frequency_list %}
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header">
            <i class="material-icons">view_day</i>{{ frequency.grouper }}&nbsp;Frequency Rate
          </div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <div class="table-responsive card-text">
              <table class="table highlight">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Product</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for item in frequency.list %}
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        {{ item.product }}
                      </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>${{ item.price }}</td>
                  </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```